# Linux Mint 17.1 XFCE does not have Printer support pre-installed. Can I add it, and precisely how?

Tags: linux-mint, printing, xubuntu

I recently tried Linux Mint 17.1 XFCE and really liked it. But the only big issue is there seems to be no Printer utilities installed by default. And yes there are packages available through the Synaptic Package manager. But I don't know which ones. I tried the KDE printer manager and selected the package that included all drivers. But it using it, doesn't seem to have the option to connect via USB. Only via the Network. Can this be easily resolved? It works perfectly fine under Xubuntu. Scanning and Printing.

If it matters, the printer I am using is a Kodack EPS Office 2170

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd comment in this thread may still hold true, although rather old, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1890560.

It basically says the all-in-one printers are not supported for Linux.

With that being said, I'd highly recommend connecting it your LAN if possible.  This makes it much easier to administer.  Heck, it's worth a shot.

Setting up a network printer in Linux Mint 17.1 is relatively easy.  The most important thing to now when installing network printers is the IP address.  Be sure the network printer has a static IP.  Once you verify it does, open MENU << Printers, click Add, Network Printer and lastly choose Find Network Printer, the only thing left to do now is enter the IP address of the network printer.  Linux Mint is pretty good about obtaining the proper drivers once it detects the printer via IP address.

I ran Mint 17.1 Rebecca Xfce for months before upgrading to Rafaela 17.2 Cinnamon x64, and I have never had issue with installing network printers using Mint.

Comment: I can't find this `MENU << Printer` you mentioned. In fact, I can't find any mention of Printers anywhere in any system menu or the control center. This despite the fact that I have three network printers connected. It's very strange.